# Recreating a slice when adding a new element

Tags: go, slice

I have a task to add the number of inserts into the database to the slice. Since I don't know how many results I will actually have, I use `make([]int,0)`.

```
func getResult(n int) []int {
    var result = make([]int, 0)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        count := insert()
        if count > -1 {
            result = append(result, count)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

But it seems that if `n` is large enough, then using `append` will cause slice to be recreated every time, which seems to me to be overhead.

How can this be avoided or optimized?

Probably, this can be solved using `make([]int, 0, n)`, but then I can't distinguish in slice `{1,1,0,0}` - the zeros at the end are the result of `insert()` or the absence of a value. This is a pretty simple example, but I was trying to explain the problem I'm trying to solve with it.

Comment: The statement „ then using append will cause slice to be recreated every time“ is factually wrong. Ignore your concerns. If you cannot: benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
func getResult(n int) []int {
    var result = make([]int, 0, n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        count := insert()
        if count > -1 {
            result = append(result, count)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

The function call `make([]int, 0, n)` returns a slice with length `0` and capacity `n`.

Each element of `result` slice is a valid result. To say this another way, the elements of `result` with indices `0` through `len(result)-1` are valid results.

The slice can have extra capacity where `cap(result) > len(result)`.  Ignore the extra capacity.

https://go.dev/play/p/kRVFLI1znUC

Answer (score -5):

You can make a count variable and then slice it at the end:

```
func getResult(n int) []int {
    var result = make([]int, 0, n)
    c := 0
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        if count := insert(); count > -1 {
            result[c] = count
            c++
        }
    }
    return result[:c]
}
```

This way, you can distinguish how many elements were in fact added.

Comment: This will panic immediately when trying to set `result[c]` (as `result` is a slice of length 0).